# Change pixels of a specific color to another color, across all layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, layers, pixel, cs4

I am drawing an image that's going to be parsed by a program.  It expects very specific pixel colors, in this case black 0x000000FF (full alpha) to work properly.

... I made a whoops!  Randomly, some of the pixels that should be pure black are actually 0x000100FF (just green enough to cause a problem).  The data is spread across over 200 layers, so fixing this by hand would be heart breakingly tedious.

Is there a way to change pixels with the color 0x000100FF, to the color of 0x000000FF (black) across all layers?

Comment: ... prepare for heartbreak, unfortunately.

Comment: What else is on the document? Just this 0x000000FF or are some elements needing to keep something else? And what resolution/image format do you need the output to be if anything specific.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18441/how-do-i-change-all-instances-of-a-color-to-another-in-photoshop?rq=1

Comment: You can try creating a "Replace Color" Action that will replace that specific color with black, but I _think_ you'd have to manually run it on each layer, which is a bummer with 200 layers.

Comment: aw, I ended up writing something to do the operation to the exported layers outside of PS.  Which was a little tedious but it's prolly the easiest way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open "Levels" and zoom in as close as you can on one of the incorrect pixels.
   [image]
2. Using the Black Eye Dropper within the Levels window, click on the bad pixel. It will change all pixels of that color (and darker) to pure black.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Do what other people are saying about creating the "replace color" action, then put all the layers in a folder and apply the action to the folder.

Comment: Hi Nate! Can you explain what other people are saying and add these details in your answer? It will probably less confusing this way as you're the official answer!